# How do I access a module from an instance method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.4

Suppose I have a module:

```
module M
  def self.foo
    ...
  end

  def bar
    ...
  end
end
```

Module `M` is included in a class.

```
class A
  include M
end
```

I want to call `foo` from `bar`, which will eventually be called on an instance of `A`. What's the best way to do this inside `bar`?

Of course I can just say `M.foo`, but that's duplication of the module's name, which feels unnecessary.

Comment: _"I want to call foo from bar"_ – if there was an `A.foo` in addition to `M.foo`, which `foo` would you want to call?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `M.foo`? That seems to me the logical thing to do. It does seem odd to have both the class method and instance method in the same module., considering that you want to invoke the first and include the second.

Comment: There is no relationship whatsoever between an instance of `A` and `M`'s singleton class. In particular, `M`'s singleton class is not in `A`'s inheritance chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, in a `module`, it's a good practice to have class-methods and instance-methods separate, like this:

```
module M
  def bar
    puts "BAR"
    self.class.foo
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def foo
      puts "FOO"
    end
  end
end
```

Now, in a class, I would ideally want to `include` this module `M` in a way that I get `A.foo` as class method and `A.new.bar` as instance method. The trick for that is [`Module.included`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-included).

```
module M
  def bar
    puts "BAR"
    self.class.foo
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def foo
      puts "FOO"
    end
  end

  # when module is included, extend the class with ClassMethods
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end
end

class A
  include M
end

A.singleton_methods #=> [:foo]

A.new.foo
#=> BAR
#=> FOO
```

With this approach, you can refer the class method with `self.class` and it will automagically work.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of this! Since it seems there is no solution which avoids including `foo` in `A`, and I understand why thanks to Jorg's comment, I'll accept this answer as the closest to what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Not really elegant, but

```
def bar
  Module.nesting.last.foo
end
```

should do it.

Note that `Module#nesting` returns an array because one module might be nested into another module. In the general case, you need to apply the correct array index to pick the module you want to have.

Answer (score 0):

I think using `M.foo` is best, but as an exercise, one could change `M#bar` as follows.

```
module M
  def self.foo
    puts "In self.foo"
  end

  def bar
    puts "In bar"
    method(__method__).owner.foo
  end
end

class A
  include M
end

a = A.new
a.bar
  # In bar
  # In self.foo
```

Comment: Consider using `__caller__` instead of `__method__` to make it possible to alias methods and make the code still work.